# How to compare values in php database

Tags: php, sql, compare

From the table image below:

[image]

Is there any ways that I used nodeID 101 as my indicator. Then I want to retrieve battery value of Node102 which is lower than the battery value of NodeID101... Same goes to node103, it will also compare with node101 whereby if its battery value lower than node101, result is displayed.

Thanks for your guides!

```
<?php

$username="root";
$password="";
$database="testing";
mysql_connect('localhost',$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to select database");

$query = "SELECT * FROM monitoring WHERE Battery < 2.7";
$result = mysql_query($query);

echo "<b><center>Database Output</center></b><br><br>";

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>PC_Timestamp </th>
<th>NodeID </th>
<th>PacketID </th>
<th>RSSI </th>
<th>Node_Timestamp </th>
<th>Temperature </th>
<th>Battery </th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['PC_Timestamp'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['NodeID'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['PacketID'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['RSSI'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Node_Timestamp'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Temperature'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Battery'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysql_close(); 
?>
```

Comment: Please add the external content to your question and tell us what you've already tried (your sql code).

Comment: When you say lower battery value than node 101, what do you mean exactly? Multiple items have node 101 and these have varying battery values. It sounds like a very simple SQL query is required but I can't begin to help until I understand the logic of what you are wanting to do